# ps -ef output clearance

Tags: unix, ps

Please, see the below output:

## ps -ef | grep cfengine

root      1739     1  0  2016 ? 
       00:11:56 /usr/localcw/opt/cfengine/bin/cfservd

root      3311     1  0  2016 ?
   00:10:38 /usr/localcw/opt/cfengine/bin/cfexecd
root     30363  3311  0 06:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/localcw/opt/cfengine/bin/cfagent -Dfrom_cfexecd:scheduled_run
root     31001 19936  0 06:08 pts/0    00:00:00 grep cfengine
#

In the last row of the output we can see "grep cfengine" as one of the process which was active while the command was run.

Now, Please see the below mentioned output:

## ps -ef | grep [c]fengine

root      1739     1  0  2016 ?        00:11:56 /usr/localcw/opt/cfengine/bin/cfservd
root      3311     1  0  2016 ?        00:10:38 /usr/localcw/opt/cfengine/bin/cfexecd
root     30363  3311  0 06:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/localcw/opt/cfengine/bin/cfagent -Dfrom_cfexecd:scheduled_run
#

applying the regex([c]), filtered out the process "grep cfengine".

Can someone please explain this behavior of the shell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Different shells treat [ and ] differently, by the way, trying out stuff as root is dangerous. Which shell are you using ?

Comment: korn shell. But in this case, is [ and ] is being used as wildcard or regular expression?

Comment: Probably because the process after the pipe "|" -  `grep` command with regex pattern as argument, ends up being treated as it is entered by user(as a whole string), but the argument is not matched by the `grep` while it actually executes.